# how to find a div in a collection of divs that has its display property set

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is built with divs. The user can click on a "vitals table", which will slide down its "details table". When collapsed, jQuery sets the details table's display property to "none". When visible, the display property is "table".

I need to be able to identify if one of the details tables is visible and save the id of the button in that vitals table, so that, when I need to reload/repopulate the table, I can have that details table visible again after the reload.

```
<div id="mainTable">
    <div class="recordRow">
        <div class="recordCell">
            <div class="vitalsTable">
                <div class="vitalsRow">
                    <div class="vitalsCell">
                        <label>some text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vitalsCell">
                        <!-- button id is unique to identify the Record Row -->
                        <button id="btnViewEditRecord-4" value="Details" title="Click to View and Edit this Record">Details</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detailsTable" style="display: table;">
                <div class="detailsRow">
                    <div class="detailsCell">
                        <label>some text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailsCell">
                        some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="recordRow">
        <div class="recordCell">
            <div class="vitalsTable">
                <div class="vitalsRow">
                    <div class="vitalsCell">
                        <label>some text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="vitalsCell">
                        <!-- button id is unique to identify the Record Row -->
                        <button id="btnViewEditRecord-5" value="Details" title="Click to View and Edit this Record">Details</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="detailsTable" style="display: none;">
                <div class="detailsRow">
                    <div class="detailsCell">
                        <label>some text</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detailsCell">
                        some text
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried doing something like

```
if ($('#peopleListTable').find('.personDetailsTable').prop('display') == 'table') {
```

but that didn't work.

How can I accomplish this?

**UPDATE**
I'm rephrasing my question for the sake of clarity. The above information is still relevant, though:

How do I return the id of the button whose next div has its display property set to table?

Comment: Why dont you make things easier? Why not just adding a class at the same time that you change the `display` property of those elements and then just look for elements with that class using [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)?

Comment: Only one (if any) of the divs in the `#mainTable` div is going to have the display property set to "table". I need to find that div and get the id of the button in that div. So there's really no point in adding another class, when the display: table will already be unique to just one div.

Comment: yeah, there is a reason. This is how usually is done in jQuery. (classes used as status) It will be a faster selector (by far) and it will improve the readability of the code, which is what programmers should be looking for in most cases. If you want to go for the complicate path, take it. I'm just giving advice.

Comment: Okay, in either case, whether I add another class or look for the value of the display property, how do I return the id of the button whose next div has its display property set to table (or has the added class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for this:

```
var buttonId = $('.detailsTable').filter(
  // only grab divs that have a display of table in their "style" declaration
  function () {
      return $(this).css('display') === 'table';
  })
  // look in the previous DIV for a button element, and grab it's ID
  .prev().find('button').attr('id');
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NhGS/)**

That said, I would consider restructuring your html/rethinking your approach as this is highly dependent on your HTML structure. As noted in the comments, using classes to identify your elements, rather than depending on inline styles, would be a better approach.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at adjusting my approach.